IJCAD(64bit版)のVBAでListViewを使用したい
IJCAD 2024(64bit版)のVBAでListViewを使用する方法があれば教えていただけないでしょうか？
2024より前は32bit版を使用していたためListViewが使用できていましたが、
2024から64bit版のみになったため、移行を試みたところListViewが使用できないことがわかりました。
以下の質問を参考にOffice365(64bit版)をインストールしたところ、OfficeのVBAではListViewが使用できましたが、IJCADでは使用できませんでした。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096072/is-it-possible-to-generate-an-excel-vba-listview-on-a-64bit-machine
皆様にご教示いただきたくよろしくお願いいたします。
